# How to continue the framed text box on multiple pages?

Tags: page-breaking, boxes, framed

I am using `framed` package to create text boxes using `begin{framed}` and `end{framed}`. My problem is that my framed box goes on for two pages, and I don't want the text box to complete itself at the end of the first page and begin anew on the second page (i.e. it appears as one text box and not two)...

Is there a way to disappear the lines which are at the end of the first page's box and the top of the second page box?

Example: the same framed box on two pages, but appearing as two separate boxes!!
[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package which extends [`framed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/framed) (and is rather configurable compared to its ancestor):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
  \lipsum
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the md package works!! thx

Comment: a tip: use style=2 in \usepackage. otherwise Adobe Reader (10.0) won't show the frames....

Comment: @umar: Good advice. In Adobe Reader they wont be shown at every zoom level. Making the lines thicker also helps.

Comment: @umar, Adobe Reader 9.x behaves the same.

Comment: @Andrey do you know how can I do this with lyx?

Answer (score 25):

An alternative package to `mdframed` is [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox). Among some other interesting features, includes `breakable` framed boxes.

Using `default` style a simple example could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{15cm}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]