# mdframed and wrapfig

Tags: environments, wrapfigure, mdframed

Before starting the question, I apologize for the large pictures. I had to use some long text to demonstrate the problem.

---

To generate something like:

[image]

I used the following command:

```
\setlength{\intextsep}{-1.5pt}
\begin{boxedminipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{wrapfigure}[3]{l}[0pt]{0pt}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5in]{Information.pdf}
        \hspace{-8pt}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{boxedminipage}
```

However, `boxedminipage` does not split across pages, and I had to use `mdframed` as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13506/13508#13508). So, the above code becomes like this:

```
\setlength{\intextsep}{-1.5pt}
\begin{mdframed}
    \begin{wrapfigure}[3]{l}[0pt]{0pt}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5in]{Information.pdf}
        \hspace{-8pt}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{mdframed}
```

Unfortunately, the effect is not as expected:

[image]

> How can I use `mdframed` and `wrapfig` together?

**PS:** The `framed` package does not seem to suffer from this problem; however, its output is not satisfactory for my purposes: `framed` *closes* the frame when it is split across page boundaries, and *reopens* it on the next page. This does not show that the frame is *to be continued* on the next page. To see what I mean, compare the output of

```
\begin{framed}
    \lipsum
\end{framed}
```

and

```
\begin{mdframed}
    \lipsum
\end{mdframed}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of using the `wrapfig` package, you could use the TeX primitive `\parshape` to "make room" for the image; something along these lines (of course, change the lengths to use the values that best suit your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\mylena
\setlength\mylena{.6in}
\newlength\mylenb

\newenvironment{myframe}
  {\begin{mdframed}
    \setlength\mylenb{\linewidth}
    \addtolength\mylenb{-0.6in}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5in,height=0.5in]{Information.pdf}\par\vskip-3\baselineskip
    \parshape 4 0.6in \mylenb 0.6in \mylenb 0.6in \mylenb 0in \linewidth
  }
  {\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myframe}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{myframe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used the `demo` option of the `graphicx` package to make my example compilable for everyone; do not use that option in your actual code.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the package `lettrine`:

[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
\lettrine[image,lines=3]{Information}{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

This MWE need a real `Information.pdf` with the appropiate width and height but

[image: Information symbol] saved as `Information.png` is fine for the MWE although with lower quality.

For a demo with `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` or tunning the picture size, please change the `\lettrine` line by:

```
\lettrine[lines=3]{\includegraphics[width=0.5in,height=0.5in]{Information}}
```