# How to align mdframed inside another frame?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, mdframed, nesting

I tried to create a child frame inside a parent frame by `mdframed` as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[frametitlerule=true,frametitlerulewidth=1pt,frametitle=Parent]
\begin{mdframed}[frametitlerule=true,frametitlerulewidth=1pt,userdefinedwidth=150pt,align=right,frametitle=Child]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\lipsum
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Question1:** How to wrap text around the child frame? Filling the empty space on the left with the text of parent frame.

**Question2:** The child frame title will conquer the parent frame title. Thus, we will not have the parent frame title, but an induced copy of the child frame title. How to keep the frame titles independently?

Comment: Question2: according to the package author, this is impossible with the current version: see [mdframed nested frametitle bug](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48534/3954).

Comment: Do you need page breaking for your "child"?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel yes, it is a useful feature of `mdframed` which I do not want to miss. The content of child frame may be long flowing to the next page. Moreover, we do not know where the parent frame starts, maybe it's the bottom of page; thus, child can continue to the next page,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To both requests I have to answer with no.

The first one can be implemented but I'm not able to do the second one. I have no idea how to solve the following problem.

To illustrate my problem here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\vbox{\kant[1]}
\setbox\mybox\vsplit\mybox to 3cm
\box\mybox

\setbox\mybox=\vbox{\vbox{\kant[1]}}
\setbox\mybox\vsplit\mybox to 3cm
\box\mybox
\end{document}
```

EDIT: If you don't need a page break inside the nested `mdframed` environment you can use the following code which uses the package `cutwin`.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{twoopt}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\opencutright
\begin{document}

\section{Text}

\def\windowpagestuff{\par%
\begin{mdframed}[frametitlerule=true,frametitlerulewidth=1pt,userdefinedwidth=150pt,align=right,frametitle=Child,nobreak]
\lipsum[3]
\end{mdframed}%
%\rule[2cm]{2cm}{8cm}%
}
\begin{mdframed}[frametitlerule=true,frametitlerulewidth=1pt,frametitle=Parent,]
Text
\begin{cutout}{2}{150pt}{0pt}{30}
\let\par\relax\lipsum[2]\lipsum[1]
\end{cutout}
\lipsum
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

The result of the first page will be

[image]

Comment: I understand the situation. I hope to find a solution for this, making `mdframed` more powerful. This is of particular importance, as this behavior is practically missed in all latex packages (no practical solution). What is your solution to build child frames without `pagebreak`? This is what `wrapfig` does, but I prefer `mdframed` as it has better features to play on.

Comment: @Ali: Do you want to know a solution where no page break is needed for the child? Do I understand you correct?

Comment: Yes, it is better than nothing. I am currentling using `minipage` within `wrapfig` to do so. It is better to do everything with `mdframed` as the parent is already `mdframed`.

Comment: @Ali: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it's an interesting solution, but I doubt if it can be practical. You are indeed attaching two independent frames with `cutwin`; not dealing with the child frame within the parent framework. This is not suitable for complicated documents having several `mdframed` parent frames. What I like about `mdframed` is that it somehow keeps the frame separate from the reset of the document.

Comment: @Ali: There is an other approach using `\parshape` and a modification of some internals of `mdframed`. But this isn't such simple that I can solve it in 5 minutes ;-)

Comment: @Ali: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23402/mdframed-and-wrapfig