# Misalignment with cutwin

Tags: wrap

Compiling the code below yields a misalignment of the text when the box is drawn.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{\flushright\rule{2cm}{2cm}}%
\opencutright%
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{cutout}{1}{0.79\linewidth}{0pt}{5}%
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{cutout}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Would you know nice tricks to avoid this behavior?

Comment: You can also use `wrapfigure`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a small issue with the environment itself.

First of all you have to setup the environment as a single paragraph.(see documentation)

Next I redefined the environment itself by using the great package `regexpatch`:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{cutwin,kantlipsum,mwe}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\opencutright
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{\centering\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}%

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\cutout}{\leavevmode\hrule \@height\z@ \@width\linewidth\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\kant[3]

\begin{cutout}{2}{0.7\linewidth}{0pt}{5}%
\kant[1]
\end{cutout}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should the package be corrected? Also, in your example, we can still notice a slight misalignment introduced by `cutwin`. Thanks

Comment: @pluton: Indeed. I didn't notice this misalignment. In my opinion I would change some internals and especially the implementation of the environment itself. I prefer an environment based on `list`.

Comment: which one? because I am trying to use a cutwin like environment in your `mdframed` environment and the only one working so far is `cutwin`

Comment: @pluton: I like the possibility by parshape: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23402/mdframed-and-wrapfig/23412#23412

Comment: yes, this is probably the best. I could adapt to my case.