# boxes spanning several pages

Tags: page-breaking, boxes

I defined some time ago a box environment with the following features:

- It has a frame-color and a background color
- It stores the marginnotes, if any, and restore them at the end of the box. I use for this the commands `\mpgmpar@savemarginpars` and `\mpgmpar@restoremarginpars` from the package `minipage-marginpar`

It worked "perfectly", but now i need to put a very long text in these boxes, and there is not page break. 
My actual code, which is clearly far from optimal, is :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minipage-marginpar}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\newcommand{\strokecolor}{}
\newcommand{\fillcolor}{}
\newlength{\currentparskip}


\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mabox}[3]{%
\renewcommand{\strokecolor}{#2}
\renewcommand{\fillcolor}{#3}
\begin{Sbox}%
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}% save the value of paragraph skip
\begin{minipage}{#1}%
\setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}% restore the value
\mpgmpar@savemarginpars
}%
{\end{minipage}\end{Sbox}\fcolorbox{\strokecolor}{\fillcolor}{\TheSbox} mpgmpar@restoremarginpars}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{mabox}{10cm}{blue}{gray}
0000

\blindtext \blindtext

11111

\blindtext \blindtext

2222

\blindtext \blindtext

3333

\blindtext \blindtext
\end{mabox}
\end{document}
```

So, how could I modify the definition of `mabox`, so that I keep the present features, and that the box would span several pages if the content is very long ?

Comment: mdframed package is good for boxes of this sort (you'll find many examples on this site)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to continue the framed text box on multiple pages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13506/how-to-continue-the-framed-text-box-on-multiple-pages)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[style=1,leftmargin=0pt,rightmargin=0pt]{mdframed}


\makeatletter

\newenvironment{boxtype1}{%
\begin{mdframed}%
[linewidth=.5,margin=8.5,backgroundcolor=gray!20,linecolor=black,fontcolor=black]%
\fontsize{9}{12}\sffamily\selectfont%
}{\end{mdframed}}


\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{boxtype1}
0000

\blindtext \blindtext

11111

\blindtext \blindtext

2222

\blindtext \blindtext

3333

\blindtext \blindtext

\end{boxtype1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Could you please add some explanation to your code example to make it easer for others to understand and adapt your solution?

Comment: For me, LaTeX objected to the "margin=" option, but allowed leftmargin and rightmargin.