# How to create a breakable whitebox with fixed height

Tags: page-breaking, boxes

I want to create a whitebox with empty space (in order for people to write in it when the document in printed) but i can't find any solution to do that.
I tried tcolorbox but I can't fix the height of my box when it is breakable.
Other thing I tried is putting a vspace into my box but the frame does not fit the white space.

I basically need to be able to set a specific height of white space that can be separated between pages.

Do you have any clue ?
Thanks.

PS : my attempt :

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
    my Question is bla bla bla ?
        \vspace{25cm} % space for the answer that should be breakable between pages

\end{tcolorbox}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you express the height in *number of lines*?

Comment: no problem what so ever, any unit is good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
blblbllb

\foreach\x in {1,2,...,60}
{\strut\par}

blbll
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution this was answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46857/boxes-spanning-several-pages)
but with mdframed.  Style can be tweaked as required. Slightly edited.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[style=1,leftmargin=0pt,rightmargin=0pt]{mdframed}


\makeatletter

\newenvironment{boxtype1}{%
\begin{mdframed}%
[linewidth=.5,backgroundcolor=gray!20,linecolor=black,fontcolor=black]%
%\fontsize{9}{12}\sffamily\selectfont%
}{\end{mdframed}}


\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{boxtype1}
0000

\blindtext \blindtext

11111

\blindtext \blindtext

2222

\blindtext \blindtext

3333

\blindtext \blindtext

\end{boxtype1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Except this type of box doesn't break between pages

Comment: You shouldn't use a number in an environment name for the same reason you can't use one in a macro name. Environments work by creating macros to begin and end them, but `\boxtype1` is not valid.

Comment: noted and thanks.  Very new to this world of TeX, yet started learning and answering.  Thanks to this fantastic forum.