# Box spanning multiple pages as a float

Tags: floats, captions, boxes

I am trying to create boxes spanning over multiple pages considered as floats.

I defined boxes as floats which I can refer to using a `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment`. It works well.

I find a way to create box spanning multiple pages using the `mdframed` package. Thanks to [boxes spanning several pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46857/boxes-spanning-several-pages).

[Captioning an mdframed box without making unbreakable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135483/captioning-an-mdframed-box-without-making-unbreakable) is close but does not entirely answer my request since it does not encapsulate the box inside a floating environment I can refer to.

Here is a MWE that shows what I tried so far.  The last box will not split:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=lob,
  listname={List of boxes},
  name=Box,
  placement=htp,
]{myBox}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\newenvironment{encadrement}[1][\textwidth]
{\begin{Sbox}
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{#1}}
{\end{minipage}
        \end{Sbox}
        \fbox{\TheSbox}}

\usepackage{mdframed}



\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{myBox}

    \caption{A small box   \label{box:smallBox}}


    \begin{encadrement}
     \blindtext
    \end{encadrement}


\end{myBox}

I can here refer to the Box~\ref{box:smallBox}.

\blindtext

A big box follows, but it has no caption nor label:

\begin{mdframed}
 \Blindtext
\end{mdframed}

\blindtext

% The following box will not split as I'd like
\begin{myBox}

    \caption{A big box   \label{box:bigBox}}


    \begin{mdframed}
     \Blindtext
    \end{mdframed}


\end{myBox}


\end{document}
```

Comment: latex floats can not split but if you have an environment that does split you can give it a referenceable caption, eg `\captionof{figure}{my caption}` from the caption package.

Comment: Is this the final answer :-)? Thing is that I'd like to have the float numbered (there are already many boxes) - ie probably using the `myBox` environment ...

Comment: if you use `\captionof{figure}{....}`  it will be numbered in sequence with figures (or use table or listings or whatever other counter you are using)

Comment: Ok, now I understand! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate the use of `\captionof` with `mdframed`.  One can make it act more like a float by using `\afterpage` and `\clearpage` (afterpage package).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=lob,
  listname={List of boxes},
  name=Box,
  placement=htp,
]{myBox}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\mdfsetup{linewidth=1pt}% otherwise left line gets eaten.

\begin{document}

\blindtext

I can here refer to the Box~\ref{box:bigBox}.

\begin{mdframed}
  \captionof{myBox}{Now it has a caption and label}\label{box:bigBox}
  \Blindtext
\end{mdframed}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Well, then I have two other questions ... 1/The caption is located within the box while using this method. Is there a way to put it outside the box? (Above). 2/ Fortunately, footnotes work amazingly within boxes (not sure how but thats great). However, now, with a mdframed box, they are all located at the very end of the box, not on the page of the footnote letter (it's a letter within a box). Would you have an idea?

Comment: You could create the contents of the box as a separate document, then copy the pages one at a time using \includegraphics[page=...]{...}.  Of course the footnotes numbers would be local to the box, and the \textwidth and \textheight will need to be reduced to fit inside the box.