# making boxed or framed sections that flows to the next page

Tags: page-breaking, framed

I want to enclose a text in a box and i want the box to overflow to the next page when the box cannot fit in one page. With my code the box immediately jumps to the next page and then omit the text that can't fit. Any help or useful packages i might try

```
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.9\textwidth}|}
   \hline\\
   %frame number
\blintext[6]
\end{tabular}
```

\end{document}

Comment: You can't do it with tabular. Try one longtable, mdframed, tcolorbox.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13506/how-to-continue-the-framed-text-box-on-multiple-pages?rq=1

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks man they both do what i want.

Comment: I'm not a a man.

Comment: oh my bad...sorry about that

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I remember this line from `The Return of the King` ... ;-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm The line from Éowyn is "But no living man am I!" (in the book). I think in the film she says "I am no man."