# Create another minipage automatically

Tags: minipage

I want to list many reactions and I created an environment (which I find nice, but if you have a better idee... do not hesitate ^^)

```
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newenvironment{reactions}
{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\newcommand{\reaction}[2]{ \item [- ##1] : ##2  }
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule}
\begin{enumdescript}}
{\end{enumdescript}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\mybox}}}
```

enumdescript is enumerate and description environment (see bellow)

Thanks to those who helped me by helping others, I wanted to vote for the answers but I've not enough reputation...

But I have many reactions. Too many and one minipage is not enough. 
I know I can create a second reaction environment but it's not practical and the second numerotation will start to one.

```
\begin{reactions}
 first reactions
\end{reactions}
\begin{reactions}
 last reactions
\end{reactions}
```

But I wonder if it's possible to do this automatically...

Thank you

Ccile

PS1 : Sorry for the mistakes, do not hesitate to correct me

PS2 : here is the entire code with fake reactions if you need.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%Liste enumerate et description
\newcounter{descriptcount}  
\newlist{enumdescript}{description}{2}
\setlist[enumdescript,1]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
      \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\arabic{descriptcount}}}
  ,font=\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount~
}
\setlist[enumdescript,2]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\roman{descriptcount}}}
  ,font=\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount~
}
%Fleches rev irrev
\newcommand\irrev{\(\rightarrow \ \)}
\newcommand\rev{\(\leftrightarrow \ \)}

%Environnement reactions
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newenvironment{reactions}
{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\newcommand{\reaction}[2]{ \item [- ##1] : ##2  }
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule}
\begin{enumdescript}}
{\end{enumdescript}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\mybox}}}


\begin{document}


\section{Les réactions}
    \begin{reactions}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
    \end{reactions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Maybe you want something like `mdframed`?  See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13508/106162) for example.

Comment: or a `breakable` `tcolorbox` which is also shown is linked question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184683/1952

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `breakable` `tcolorbox` you can do:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%Liste enumerate et description
\newcounter{descriptcount}  
\newlist{enumdescript}{description}{2}
\setlist[enumdescript,1]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
      \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\arabic{descriptcount}}}
  ,font=\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount~
}
\setlist[enumdescript,2]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\roman{descriptcount}}}
  ,font=\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount~
}
%Fleches rev irrev
\newcommand\irrev{\(\rightarrow \ \)}
\newcommand\rev{\(\leftrightarrow \ \)}

%Environnement reactions
%\newsavebox{\mybox}
%\newenvironment{reactions}
%{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}

%\begin{minipage}{\linewidth - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule}
%\begin{enumdescript}}
%{\end{enumdescript}
%\end{minipage}
%\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\mybox}}}

\newtcolorbox{reactions}{breakable, 
colback=white, sharp corners,
before upper={\begin{enumdescript}},
after upper={\end{enumdescript}}}

\newcommand{\reaction}[2]{ \item [- #1] : #2  }

\begin{document}


\section{Les réactions}
    \begin{reactions}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
\reaction{name}{A + B + C + D + E \irrev F + G + H + I + J}
    \end{reactions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you !! 
Just another question : if I want to break by hand, I need to use the trick described in the manual (http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf page 375) or is there another way ? (Not the subject of the post, it's just curiosity )

And how do you show the output of the code ? I didn't find it ... 

Thanks again, and to everyone.

Ccile

Comment: @Ccile What does `break by hand` mean? You can close with `\end{reactions}` when you want and start again another `reactions` list.

Comment: If I close with `\end{reactions}` it will start another list, with a new number 1. By **break by hand** I meant choose to write for instance reactions 1 to 20 and on another page 20 to 40.

Comment: @Ccile If you close with `\end{reactions}`, the new list starts with 1 because you are using `\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}` in your definition. This way any new list will start with 1. `enumitem` offers `resume` option to break and continue list. But this option won't work with your code. If you need to `resume` broken lists, i think you should try to find an alternative code for `enumdescript`.

Comment: thanks. I was just a question, I don't need to break and continue the list.
But I suppose I can change the setcounter and put an optional parameter : if no parameter, the counter starts with 1, if there is a parameter, starts with the value given by the parameter