# How to put a no-filled box around a paragraph

Tags: boxes, documentation

I want to emphasize a certain part of a document by putting a box around it. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at `tcolorbox` or `mdframed`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36524/how-to-put-a-framed-box-around-text-math-environment/36528#36528 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13506/how-to-continue-the-framed-text-box-on-multiple-pages/184683#184683

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Wow, 43 upvotes for advising `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` in answers behind the links...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer he put enough effort in advertising :)

Comment: If you want a simple framed which can break across pages, the `framed` package is very simple to use.

Answer (score 2):

The packages `tcolorbox` and `mdframed` are both nice for filled, colored and outstanding decorated boxes, but the question is asking IMHO for the [Not So Short Introduction to LATEX2ε](http://tug.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf) to start knowing  basic commands as `\fbox` and environments as `minipage`:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\parskip{1em}
\setlength\fboxsep{1em}
\begin{document}
    Bla bla bla ...\par % you can change \par by a blank line
    \fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
        \setlength\parskip{1em}
        Bla bla bla ...\par
        And bla bla bla ...
    \end{minipage}}\par
    Bla bla bla ...
\end{document}
```